# Calculator that add products and multiplies it with tax

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Having problems figuring out a code for my calculator. I have used my textbook for help but still at a loss on why it doesn't calculate at all, just some tips would be awesome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Total Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Bananas:   <input type="text" id="bananasBox" value=""> at $ 0.50 a piece<br>
Sodas  :   <input type="text" id="sodasBox"   value=""> at $ 0.75 per can<br>
Chips  :   <input type="text" id="chipsBox"   value=""> at $1.25 per bag<br>
Candy  :   <input type="text" id="candyBox"   value=""> at $1.00 per pack<br>
TAX is 10 %
</p>
<input type="button" value="Calculate"
<button id='Calculate' onclick= "Calculate()" value="Calculate">Calculate</button>
<script type="text/javascript">


function Calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    var tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;

    total = cost*tax;
    document.getElementById("total").value = total;

document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= 'Your TOTAL is: ' + total;">
}
</script>
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the quotes of 'Calculate Total'()

Comment: Where's the closing `</script>` tag? Why are the quotes around the function name? And I just notice that you seem to have the whole block inside the `onlick` value... I really recommend to get back to some JavaScript tutorial: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Programming_-_the_real_basics, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript

Comment: user means you should remove the quotes and no spaces should be in a methodName

Comment: Fix your JavaScript in the proper way and call it is function at the onclick properly, from what I am looking at you open <script> but never closes it, you never called the calculate function on the onclick, youre mixing javascript with html without proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems.

---

The HTML is invalid (the button tag stops half way through the `onclick` attribute).

The end tag for the `<script>` is missing.

---

The syntax of a function declaration in JavaScript is:

```
function identifier() { }
```

where `identifier` is the name of the function. Identifiers are not quoted and cannot have spaces in them.

---

There is no attempt to call your function anywhere in the code.

---

You make four calls to `document.getElementById`, but only one of the ids you are trying to access exists.

---

You end the function with `}` before the last call to `document.getElementById` in it.

Comment: went ahead and edited it @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

well if you had exactly followed your textbook then i dont think you would face these issues.

1. function name with a space
2. verify your input button syntax

2.1 onclick

2.2 close the tag

3 close the script tag